# PowerShell - Singleton - usage in a runspace - runspace hangs

Tags: powershell

**Given**:

- Using PowerShell 5.1
- A powershell script that runs successful on the console
- using multiple includes/modules and oop classes.
- using singleton classes

**When**:

- running in a runspace.

```
          $rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
          $PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
          $PowerShell.runspace = $rs
          $rs.Open()
          [void]$PowerShell.AddScript(<script ps1 file>)
          [void]$PowerShell.AddArgument(<param x>)
          $PowerShell.Invoke()
```

- debugging the runspace

**Then**:

1. the runspace hangs at a code statement where

   - the singleton is addressed
   - a method of the singleton is addressed to alter one of its properties

**My goal**:

To execute multiple script files in parallel

**My questions**:

- Why may it potentially fail in the 1st place? Has it something to do with thread safety? If so; how can I try to resolve it..
- Is there a best practice for using singletons (with the ability to alter property states) throughout runspaces?

```
class Singleton {

    hidden static [Singleton] $_instance = [Singleton]::new()

    static [Singleton] $Instance = [Singleton]::GetInstance()

    [Guid] $SingletonTarget = [Guid]::NewGuid()

    hidden Singleton() {
    }

    hidden static [Singleton] GetInstance() {
        return [Singleton]::_instance
    }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/guitarrapc/2fde990d166286459c309b7cab03938b

Comment: I can only partially reproduce this behavior. The debugger unexpectedly breaks on accessing `[Singleton]::Instance`, but execution continues correctly on `c` as expected, no "hanging". Can you show an example of a method that triggers the behavior?

Comment: I use `s` and can see that at a particular code statement trying to address a custom method of the singleton that implcitely tries to alter the state of a property fails (due to hanging).

Comment: I will include an example to showcase it

Comment: I have completely isolated it and for now it seems to work!. My educated guess is that it doesn work well if you include other scripts where you also address the singleton. Somehow it will hang in that situation. I cant comprehend it yet

Comment: it seems to go wrong if you embed a reference to the singleton in another class

Comment: Still eagerly awaiting sample code with which to repro :)

Comment: will do my utmost. :-)

Comment: It had to do with the way I implemented its methods. Probably due to my lack of knowlegde how to use a singleton properly.